# Spring - injected variable is null

Tags: java, spring, javafx, dependency-injection

I'm trying to use Spring DI with JavaFx I have a MainController class what is loaded in the AppConfig as a Bean, then another MenuController class, that would be using the MainService. But the injected service is null, when called.

#### Questions

- What could be the reason, that it doesn't injects the variable?
- In an example in the setControllerFactory method they returned appContext.getBean(clazz), but I from the configuration file don't know how to access the context. How and to what do I need to set the factory?
- Do I need to recursively wire the Beans?

#### My Code

**App class:**

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfiguration.class);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        MainController mainController = context.getBean(MainController.class);
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainController.getView());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        recursiveWire(context, mainController.getView());
        primaryStage.show();
    }  

    public void recursiveWire(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context, Object root) throws Exception {
        context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(root);
        context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().initializeBean(root, null);

        for (Field field : root.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(FXML.class) && !Node.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                recursiveWire(context, field.get(root));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    
}
```

**AppConfiguration class:**

Here I've tried to set the ControllerFactory as I saw somewere suggested, but it did not change the result.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public MainService mainService() {
        return new InMemoryMainService();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    @DependsOn("mainService")
    public MainController mainController() throws IOException {
        return (MainController) loadController("/java/com/akos/fxml/Main.fxml");
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public MenuController menuController() throws IOException {
        return (MenuController) loadController("/java/com/akos/fxml/Menu.fxml");
    }

    protected Object loadController(String url) throws IOException {
        InputStream fxmlStream = null;
        try {
            fxmlStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(url);
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(url));
            Node view = loader.load(fxmlStream);
            AbstractController  controller = loader.getController();
            loader.setControllerFactory(clazz -> controller);
            controller.setView(view);
            return controller;
        } finally {
            if (fxmlStream != null) {
                fxmlStream.close();
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

**MenuController class:**

Here is where I would need to access the mainService, but it is null.

```
public class MenuController extends AbstractController implements Initializable {
   ...

    @Inject
    MainService mainService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        disableMenuElements();
        mainService.currentProgramProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        ...
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `public MainService mainService()` instead of `public InMemoryMainService mainService()` and explicitly define _menuController_ depends on _mainService_ `@Bean
    @Scope("prototype") @DependsOn("mainService")
    public MenuController menuController()`

Comment: Tried it but no change. Here is the log: [http://pastebin.com/35hur8Uh](http://pastebin.com/35hur8Uh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order in which things happen.

From the Spring perspective, when you request the bean, it is created by calling the `menuController()` method in your application config, then the `@Inject`-annotated fields are initialized (via reflection), then it returns the bean.

However, the `menuController()` method creates the controller by loading the fxml file, and then retrieving the controller from the `FXMLLoader`. The `initialize()` method in the controller is invoked by the `FXMLLoader` as part of the `load()` process. Clearly, this happens before your `menuController()` returns (because it happens before `loader.load()` returns); so `initialize()` is invoked before Spring has a chance to initialize the injected fields.

The quickest fix may be to define a setter method for the service and simply to invoke the methods on the service when it is initialized:

```
public class MenuController extends AbstractController implements Initializable {
    // ...

    private MainService mainService;

    @Inject
    public void setMainService(MainService mainService) {
        this.mainService = mainService ;
        mainService.currentProgramProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
           //  ...
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        disableMenuElements();
    }
}
```

I tend to use a different approach entirely when I use Spring to manage my JavaFX applications. Instead of giving the controllers access to the view, and then retrieving the view from the controller, I just tell the `FXMLLoader` to use Spring to instantiate the controller, via the `controllerFactory`. Then when you call `load()` on the `FXMLLoader`, it requests the controller from Spring as a bean, and consequently the `FXMLLoader` receives a bean which has all its dependencies injected. Then when it invokes `initialize()` on the controller, the dependencies are already present.

So

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    // ??? surely a service should be singleton, not prototype, scope...
    @Scope("prototype")
    public MainService mainService() {
        return new InMemoryMainService();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public MainController mainController() throws IOException {
        return new MainController();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public MenuController menuController() throws IOException {
        return new MenuController();
    }


}
```

and your menu controller is just as you had it:

```
public class MenuController extends AbstractController implements Initializable {
    // ...

    @Inject
    MainService mainService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        disableMenuElements();
        mainService.currentProgramProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            // ...
        });
    }
}
```

And now you can do

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfiguration.class);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // should fix name, you should not start your own pacakge names "java"
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/java/com/akos/fxml/Main.fxml"));
        loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    
}
```

Note that you can get a reference to the controller in the application code by calling

```
MainController mainController = loader.getController();
```

*after* you have called `loader.load()`. This gives you a reference to the controller the `FXMLLoader` created; i.e. the one that Spring created (because the controller factory instructed the `FXMLLoader` to use Spring). (In my opinion, though, you really shouldn't need a reference to the controller; the controller specifically knows how to communicate between the view and the model (service); if you want to externally change the UI you should be updating the model to do so, and then the controller will observe changes in the model and update the view.)

I'm not entirely clear what the "recursive wiring" is supposed to do. If you are loading your menu via a `<fx:include>` in the main fxml file, the controller factory will propagate to the included fxml file, so the `MenuController` will be instantiated from the spring context as well, as will have the service injected as required. If you are loading it somewhere else, you just have to set the controller factory when you load it, as shown for the main fxml file above. All this assumes your controllers are specified in the fxml file with `<fx:controller>`, which I think must be the case from your other code.

Comment: As you could see this is my first attempt to work with spring so everything is new. Thank you for this awesome and comprehensive answer. :)